CommandLineParameters '["TestPassword"]'
How to pass command line parameter: ["TestPassword"] in windows 11 such that the application see the command line parameter internally as:
["TestPassword"]
Windows 11 seems to filter out the " ". [ ] may also be treated as something special in windows 11.
Example:
SomeExe.exe ["TestPassword"]

The Windows Command Processor cmd.exe interprets a string enclosed in " as literally to interpret argument string with only % for environment/dynamic variable reference, beginning of a loop variable reference inside a FOR loop, or an argument string reference on processing a batch file and ! for delayed expanded environment/dynamic variable reference on enabled delayed variable expansion is still interpreted special. An argument string containing one or more " cannot be passed at all to a batch file.

It is possible in a command prompt window to pass a string like ["TestPassword"] to a batch file or an executable really as  ["TestPassword"] as it can be seen with a batch file name Test.cmd containing just the line @echo First argument: %1. But it depends on the command line parser of the executable usually run before calling the function main how the command line string is split up into argument strings and passed to function main of the executable. Most command line parsers split up the entire command line string using normal space and " as separators.

In other words if ["TestPassword"] is not interpreted as one argument string by the executable which is started by cmd.exe or any other executable with a call of the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess with function parameter lpCommandLine pointing to the string of the command line with ["TestPassword"], you must read the documentation of the executable how to pass a password string containing " to the executable.

Most executables do not support passing an argument string containing one or more " inside an argument string to the executable. But there are executables which support that because of a command line option is for passing JSON formatted data to the executable or a password with ". It really depends on how the executable parses the command line string. cmd.exe passes ["TestPassword"] as is to the executable as it can be seen with free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool Process Monitor.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Try escaping double quotes as follows: someapp.exe [\"TestPassword\"]…

46k combos tried with set of 6 symbols: ' " [ ] ^ space non worked for a delphi exe. :(. Strangely enough it's claimed go exe on linux works.

Possible path 1 towards a long term cross platform solution:
"
Feedback hub title: "Command Line Parsing Algorithm/Specification needed for cross-platform development Linux/Windows/Other OS-es."
Feedback hub content: "Currently the following problem exists, illustrated by vitelabs vite blockchain project:
On linux it's possible to pass a command line as follows:
govite.exe ["TestPassword"]
On windows this is not possible and "" is filtered by C runtime library used by GO to parse command lines, Delphi also filters out these "" symbols:
govite.exe ["TestPassword"]
results in:
govite.exe [TestPassword] being passed.
This problem is most likely caused by a lack of command line parsing standization/specification.
Perhaps now that Microsoft support Linux on Windows it can do some research into a command line parsing algorithm that works on both systems. perhaps even all operating systems or must of them."
"
Possible path 2 for short term quick fix:
Write custom code for Windows platform and use api to get command line parameter and circumvent existing parsing code and write own parsing code.
